# Sandbox to HTML without iframe?

Tags: html, xhtml

I have a page with dynamic content provided by a crawler. But sometimes this content has problems in the HTML (without close tag, tag closed without opening, etc). So, this wrong content breaking the whole page because closes or opens something they should not.

Common mistakes of HTML.

`<div><p>foo</p>`

`<p>bar</p></div>`

`<p><a>link</p></a>`

How put this content in a sandbox to doesn't break the page? Can't use iframes because of SEO.

Comment: Is JavaScript an option?

Comment: Preferably no. To do any handler, it's preferable to do in the backend or "middlewire".

Answer (score 1):

How about processing the dynamic content to find out which tags have not yet been closed, and (using a stack) add them at the end or where necessary (to ensure proper tag nesting)? However, if you do resort to this, I suggest performing this operation client side.

Comment: If I do this on the client side, the page will flash, because the JavaScript will run on document ready. I already know how to do this on the server side with BeautifulSoup (Python). But was wondering if there is some way to do it in HTML to not use unnecessary processing.